# Can I use this in Vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vue-resource, vue-cookies

I create project with **vue-cookies** and **vue-resource**, I try to access to the cookies with `this.$cookies.get('my-cookie')` and request my API with `this.$http.post('URL')`. Tut the store can't access to `this`.

My action in store.js :

```
checkCookies: () => {
    if (this.$cookies.get('test') === null) {
        console.log('vide')
        //envoyer sur la page de connexion
    } else {
        console.log('pas vide')
        this.$http.post('URL', {

        })
    }
}
```

How I call my action (it's method call on click) :

```
test() {
        return this.$store.dispatch('checkCookies')
      }
```

How I my test function is called:

```
<v-btn @click="test">cookies!</v-btn>
```

I have this error when I run `checkCookies` :

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _this is undefined"

I would use `this` normally in my store, I know that I can import each packages one by one to use them but, I want to know if there is way to use `this` in vuex to ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What error(s) do you get?

Comment: You want to use this(context of vuex store) to access that(context of Vue instance)?

Comment: Yes I want to keep context in vuex store

Comment: There's no arrow function, maybe when I use this.$store.dipsatch('myAction') ignore the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.$cookies` and `this.$http` work within a component method because those functions are added to `Vue.prototype` by their respective plugins.

These are just convenience methods anyway; it seems these plugins install equivalent methods on `Vue` directly:

```
this.$http    -> Vue.http
this.$cookies -> Vue.$cookies
```

If you *really* want to be able to do `this.$http` within a Vuex action, then you  need to assign the methods to the store:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({ ... })

// Make sure you have registered the Vue plugins by this point
store.$http = Vue.http
store.$cookies = Vue.$cookies
```